Holomorphic function on punctured disc such that $|z^2 f(z)|$ is bounded
Let $\mathbb{D}^* = \{|z| <1\}\setminus\{0\}$ and let $f$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}^*$. (a) What can you conclude if $|z^2 f(z)|$ is bounded. (b) Consider a family of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}^*$ and suppose there is a uniform bound on $|z^2 f(z)|$. Is this family normal.
My attempt:
(a) Let $g(z) = z^2 f(z)$. Since it is bounded around $0$, it must be a removable singularity. Then $g$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{D}$ so around 0 we have
$$g(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2 \frac{z^2}{2} + \dots$$
But then
$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2} = \frac{a_0}{z^2} + \frac{a_1}{z} + \frac{a_2}{2} + \dots$$
So $f$ has a pole at 0 of order at most 2.
(b) $g_n(z) = z^2 f_n(z)$ is uniformly bounded by assumption so it is normal by Montel’s theorem. Let $f_{n_k}$ be any subsequence. We know that $g_{n_k}$ has a convergent subsequence. Can we conclude that $f_{n_k}$ has a convergent subsequence?

How is $|z^2 f_n(z)| \le n$ a uniform bound?

You are right. It is not a uniform bound. I will fix the mistake.

If $g_{n_k}(z)$ is a convergent sequence, is $f_{n_k}(z)$ convergent?

Part (a) is correct: $z^2f(z)$ is bounded, therefore is $f(z) = g(z)/z^2$ with a holomorphic function $g: \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$.
Part (b): Let $\cal F$ be a family of functions which are holomorphic in $\Bbb D^*$ such such that $|z^2 f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in \Bbb D^*$ and all $f \in \cal F$.
Your approach does work: $\cal G = \{ z^2 f \mid f \in \cal F \}$  is uniformly bounded, so that every sequence $(f_n)$ in $\cal F$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $z^2 f_{n_k}(z) \to g(z)$ locally uniformly in $\Bbb D^*$. It follows that $f_{n_k}(z) \to f(z) := g(z)/z^2 $ locally uniformly in $\Bbb D^*$ since
$$
  |f_{n_k}(z) - f(z)| = \frac{1}{|z|^2}|z^2 f_{n_k}(z)  - g(z)|
\le \frac{1}{r^2} |z^2 f_{n_k}(z)  - g(z)|
$$
for $0 < r \le |z| \le 1$.
But it is simpler to apply Montel's theorem directly to $\cal F$. For $0 < r \le |z| \le 1$ is $|f(z)| \le M/r^2$, so that $\cal F$ is locally uniformly bounded, and therefore normal.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer!
